# Erro Cannot destructure property '_tokenResponse' of 'undefined' as it is undefined

Tags: react, typescript, firebase

Estou trabalhando num projeto para portfolio que no mesmo tem a opção de fazer login com facebook que foi implementado usando o firebase. O projeto funciona no localhost, mas no deploy que fiz na vercel ele não funciona e retorna o seguinte erro ao tentar fazer o login com o facebook:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot destructure property '_tokenResponse' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.
at On.credentialFromTaggedObject (index--fe6ooXT.js:1096:392)
at On.credentialFromResult (index--fe6ooXT.js:1096:227)
at n (index--fe6ooXT.js:2879:1624)
at index--fe6ooXT.js:2879:1959

código do meu projeto aonde está sendo trabalhado o token de acesso:

```
const Login = ({ onReceive }: receive) => {

const dispatch = useDispatch()

const handleLoginData = (result: any) => {
    const credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
    const _tokenResponse = credential?.accessToken;
    fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/${result.user.providerData[0].uid}/picture?type=large&access_token=${_tokenResponse}`)
        .then((response) => response.blob())
        .then((blob) => URL.createObjectURL(blob))
        .then((avatarProfile) => {
            const newUser = {
            id: result.user.uid,
            name: result.user.displayName,
            avatar: avatarProfile
        }
        addUsers(newUser)
        dispatch(setLoginData(newUser))
        onReceive(true)
    }
)
```

}

```
const fbData = () => {
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider).then((result) => {
        handleLoginData(result)
    })
}

return (
    <button onClick={() => fbData()}>Logar com facebook</button>
)
```

}

export default